# How do I put some text in specific position on a page horizontally with the prosper class?

Tags: positioning, textpos

Is there anyway to put text in a page horizontally at a specific position with LaTeX using the `prosper` class?

After googling, I found that the `textpos` package can be used to put text in a specific position, but the text is shown vertically. Is there any way to show the text horizontally?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[final,slideBW,total,colorBG]{prosper}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\title{Test}
\author{Name}
\email{test@test.com}
\institution{XX University}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\begin{slide}{Test Slide}
\begin{textblock}{1}(2,3)
Question
\end{textblock}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

How do I show the text "Question" at a specific position horizontally?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209191/how-to-put-some-text-in-specific-position-of-a-page-horizontally-with-prosper-cl?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 27):

you can use this solution:

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
.....
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(10cm,6cm) % {block width} (coords) 
   Your text here
\end{textblock*}
```

Comment: Nice answer! +1. Just one thing: remove the `.....` and complete the code with everything necessary from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}` to make it compilable.

Comment: Is it possible to add `textblock` but not influence other thing on the page, sort of putting it in the background wherever the coordinates states (float if possible won't be a solution probably)? And also turn it vertically? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is to position the text horizontally at the current location in the page you can use

```
\noindent\hspace{<position>}<text>
```

This is used to produce the first section of the image below.

Alternatively, if you want more flexibility in being able to specify the position as being the center of the text, or the right of the text you can use the `\PositionText` macro as defined below. It accepts three parameters:

- An optional alignment specification of either `l`, `c`, or `r` for left, center and right alignment. Defaults to `l` if not specified.
- The horizontal position
- The text

For example, the centered line in the second section of the image below is produced by:

```
\PositionText[c]{1.0in}{Centered at 1.0in}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- I set the `textwidth=3.0in` and enabled `showframe` with [the `geometry` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/) to make it clear that the text is located at the specified horizontal distance.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,textwidth=3.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xstring}% for string comparrison
\usepackage{calc}%    for \widthof
\usepackage{pgf}%     for math calclations

\newlength{\Size}
\newcommand*{\PositionText}[3][l]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {l}{\noindent\hspace{#2}#3}%
        {c}{\pgfmathsetlength{\Size}{#2-0.5*(\widthof{#3})}\noindent\hspace{\Size}#3}%
        {r}{\pgfmathsetlength{\Size}{#2-1.0*(\widthof{#3})}\noindent\hspace{\Size}#3}%
        }[\PackageError{PositionText}
            {\MessageBreak Unrecognized alignment: #1.\MessageBreak 
            Valid alignments are are `l`, `c`, `r'}{}]%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent\hspace{0.0in}Left point at 0.0in\par
\noindent\hspace{1.0in}Left point at 1.0in\par
\noindent\hspace{2.0in}Left point at 2.0in\par
\noindent\hspace{3.0in}Left point at 3.0in\par

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip
\PositionText{1.0in}{Left point at 1.0in}\par
\PositionText[c]{1.0in}{Centered at 1.0in}\par
\PositionText[r]{3.0in}{Right at 3.0in}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: \hspace{-1in} also accepts negative values.

Answer (score 2):

The class `prosper` is really outdated, use `powerdot` instead:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}

\title{Test}
\author{Name}
%\email{test@test.com}
%\institution{XX University}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{slide}{Test Slide}
\rput(2cm,-3cm){Question}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```